# Making django web application accessible from other machines without deploying to a cloud

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django web application and normally, it works on AWS but one of our customers wants to use this web application on localhost because of the security. Also he wants to use this application with more than one computer on the same host. How to make a roadmap for that without sharing source code?

Comment: You want to allow him to be able to run the server on his own machine without sharing the source code?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, I ask if there is a way to do this and how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [JPRQ](https://jprq.io) as it is a user-friendly solution that might effectively address your issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34428826)